# How to fetch all news article urls?

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, scrapy, urlfetch

I can easily scrape all news article from websites in which articles' urls are organized in this way: `http://samplenewsagency.com/en/news/12563`. Just one should generate some numbers and replace with `12563` to find another piece of news.
But what can be done for websites like `http://gcaptain.com` which organize their news in this way: `http://gcaptain.com/chinese-aircraft-carrier-sails-hong-kong-maiden-visit/`.
How can I find all news urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the given web site [gcaptain.com](http://gcaptain.com), the easiest way to go seems to be creating spider based on `CrawlSpider` class and using rules to specify which links to follow. Here's the simplest example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class GcaptainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'gcaptain'
    allowed_domains = ['gcaptain.com']
    start_urls = ['http://gcaptain.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//article//h2/a'), callback='parse_article', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_article(self, response):
        item = {}
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//article//header/h1/text()').extract_first()
        return item
```

It assumes all links to news articles can be found using XPath expression `//article//h2/a` and extracts just titles from the articles. This example won't give you all articles as the web site is using infinite scrolling mechanism, which you would have to take into account to load all news. How to do this can be read for example in [this](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/06/22/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-june-2016/) Scrapinghub blog post.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful.